# How to add locations to Shopify locations API

Tags: shopify

I want to add locations to Shopify Locations API. Please find API for locations in the below.

/admin/locations.json

I am nothing getting locations as a response of above service.  Becase didn't add any locations.  So,  I want to add locations to the API then should be able to get list of locations.

So please tell me how to add locaitions

Comment: As you can see from - https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/location, it supports only `GET`. You have to add locations manually under admin settings.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the Locations API does not allow you to write locations. As @HymnZ said, you'll need to add them through the admin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply joshubrown